# Sqlite Matching on multiple tags

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have three tables.

```
story table:
story_id, story_name, story_author

genre table:
genre_id, genre_name

pair table:
story_id, genre_id
```

How does one formulate a SQL statement that find all stories with both a romance genre and a comedy genre.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT * from pair
INNER JOIN story
ON story.story_id = pair.story_id
INNER JOIN genre
ON genre.genre_id = pair.genre_id
WHERE genre.name = "romance"
AND genre.name = "comedy"
```

but that doesn't work because in each of the rows returned I only see:
story_id, story_name, story_author, genre_id, genre_name

each row only has the one genre_name listed.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

try somthing like this:

```
SELECT story.* 
FROM story
  INNER JOIN pair firstpair
    ON firstpair.story_id = story.story_id
  INNER JOIN genre firstgenre
    ON firstgenre.genre_id = firstpair.genre_id
  INNER JOIN pair secondpair
    ON secondpair.story_id = story.story_id
  INNER JOIN genre secondgenre
    ON secondgenre.genre_id = secondpair.genre_id
WHERE firstgenre.name = 'romance' AND secondgenre.name = 'comedy'
```

this is the clumsy way to get all stories with both romance and comedy genre, you can also use a custom function to get whether the story match the condition, but I'm not sure if the function is the fast way to do it.

hope this can help~~

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent of @baiyangcao's answer, but queries that use subqueries instead of joins can be easier to understand (and are not any less efficient):

```
SELECT *
FROM story
WHERE story_id IN (SELECT story_id
                   FROM pair
                   JOIN genre USING (genre_id)
                   WHERE genre.name = 'comedy')
  AND story_id IN (SELECT story_id
                   FROM pair
                   JOIN genre USING (genre_id)
                   WHERE genre.name = 'romance');
```

It would be possible to use the same construction to remove the remaining joins, but that is probably not worth it:

```
SELECT *
FROM story
WHERE story_id IN (SELECT story_id
                   FROM pair
                   WHERE genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
                                     FROM genre
                                     WHERE name = 'comedy'))
  AND story_id IN (SELECT story_id
                   FROM pair
                   WHERE genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
                                     FROM genre
                                     WHERE name = 'romance'));
```